# Access userform throws error while refreshing the sharepoint list

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, userform, vba7

How to solve 3009 error, the error is caused when I used the below refresh code

```
Currentdb.execute("Data").refreshlink
```

the data table is exported and imported to sharepoint list

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct syntax:

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("Data").RefreshLink
```

or:

```
CurrentDb("Data").RefreshLink
```